# Regex для разбиения выражения на лексемы

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Делаю калькулятор на Java 8. Надо написать регулярное выражение для разбиение строки на лексемы. Разделителями лексем могут являться '(', ')', '+', '-', '*', '/' и ' ' - пробел.
Собираюсь сделать так :

```
String lexems[] = исходнаяСтрока.split(регулярноеВыражение);
```

Comment: отлично. напишите. (тут не выполняют работу по заданию, а помогают тем, кто уже почти все сделал, но что то не так)

Comment: Сделано всё - я просто переделываю программу с C++ на Java.

Comment: Раз вы ее просто переделываете, значит у вас видимо уже есть лексер, тогда не ясно в чем вопрос. просто перепишите старый лексер на джаве

Comment: хочу применить RegEx'ы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например можно воспользоваться [одним](https://regex101.com/) из множества онлайн помощников разработки регулярных выражений.
Если уж очень лень, то вполне можно найти готовые решения, [например](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198370/regex-for-validating-correct-input-for-calculator)